# C++ initialize list assignment in copy constructor and crashing in copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, copy

I have a situation where I am having trouble redefining a value that was defined in the initialization list.  I'd like to redefine this in the copy constructor.  I will throw down some sample code.  I am also having an issue where my program is crashing once it gets into the for loop of my copy constructor.  See anything wild going on there?  Doesn't seem to make it out of the for loop without crashing.

in the header file:

```
class Calculator : public Tool {
private:

    int numberKeys;

    Tool** tools;

public:

    Calculator();
    Calculator(const Calculator& obj);
```

in the CPP file:

```
Calculator::Calculator()
:Tool("MyCalculator"),
 numberKeys(0),
 tools(nullptr)
{
}

Calculator::Calculator(const Calculator& obj )
{

numberKeys=obj.numberKeys;
tools = new Tool*[numberKeys];

*****How do I define     :Tool("MyCalculator"),
*****to                  :Tool("YourCalculator"),

for (int x = 0; x < numberKeys; x++){
    this->tools[x] = (obj.tools[i]->clone());

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the default constructor and copy constructor for `Calculator` to pass different strings to the parent (base) class.

To do this, use the same assignment list format used for the default constructor. So the definition of the copy constructor will look like:

```
Calculator::Calculator(const Calculator& obj)
: Tool("YourCalculator"), numberKeys(obj.numberKeys) {
    tools = new Tool*[numberKeys];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberKeys; i++) tools[i] = obj.tools[i]->clone();
}
```

An extra few coding tips:

1. When delcaring member variables, I would use `m_` or `_` prefixes to destinguish from local variables. This way you don't have to keep using `this`, which can speed up coding in the long run.
2. Keep an eye on what temp veriables you use in your for loops - you declared `int x = 0`, and then used `obj.tools[i]` when `i` doesn't exist in the local scope.
3. You can comment code using `//`, or surround a comment block with `/* comment */`. `*****` will not comment out code.
4. I would refrain from initializing member variables to `nullptr` if possible. This may get confusing later on when trying to manipulate them, as it may cause a null-pointer error.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful response!